# How do you know if a router is good for 50 computers

Tags: router

My Router is not wireless and I don't wish to use wireless for my own security, I have a Bandwidth of 1024/512 mbps, but my connection drops still. People talk of my router. How Do I Know a ROUTER is good for me to connect 50 Clients.

Comment: "50 clients" as in bittorrent or some other file-sharing application?  or "50 clients" meaning 50 computers physically connecting to the router?

Comment: @quack - and if 50 actual machines, this will probably be more suited for ServerFault.

Comment: Comprehensible language and a complete description of the problem would get you much better answers, just saying. You can use the "edit" link underneath the text of your question to add more detail.

Comment: Do you really have a 1Gbit/sec down, 512Mbit/sec up connection to the Internet, or do you mean Kbps?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is relative. If you have a high grade low contention ratio such as 10:1 or even 4:1 or 1:1 then 1024 / 512 Kbps would be sufficient, PROVIDED you don't have heavy load.

However if you have a shared connection, say ADSL with 50:1, and 30 of your users are using BitTorrent (or even 3), your connection will suffer.